# Prove that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|^2dx \leq 2\sup\limits_{x \in [-\pi, \pi]}f(x) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm styding harmonic analysis and the book i'm reading takes for a fact that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|^2dx \leq 2\sup\limits_{x \in [-\pi, \pi]}f(x) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|dx$$
And if $\sup\limits_{x \in [-\pi, \pi]}f(x)=\|f\|_{\infty}$. Then the above inequality is:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|^2dx \leq 2\|f(x)\|_{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|dx$$

Where $f,g : [-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $2\pi$-periodic functions and $\|g\| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \quad \forall x \in [-\pi, \pi]$.
**My attempt:**

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \| f(x)-g(x)\|^2dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} ( f(x)-g(x))^2dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f^2(x)+g^2(x)-2f(x)g(x))dx \leq \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f^2(x)+g^2(x)-2\|f(x)\|_{\infty}^2)dx$$
And that's about it.

Comment: there is no way this is true, take for example $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: @dezdichado there are some hypotheses

Comment: $\int_a^b|f-g|^2\,dx\leq\|f-g\|_{\infty}\int_a^b|f-g|\,dx\leq 2\|f\|_{\infty}\int_a^b|f-g|\,dx$, where we used the triangle inequality, $\|f-g\|_{\infty}\leq \|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}\leq 2\|f\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you!!